# nvidia display adapter downgraded itself to HD

Tags: video, computers, display

I am experiencing something strange in one of my laptops that I haven't seen before. The laptop is an [ASUS K52JC](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/K52JC/#specifications), has an Nvidia Geforce 310M. I have it setup as a dual boot with both windows 7 and windows 8.

It has worked fine for about 2 years. However, today windows suddenly crashed. After a reboot, the nvidia control panel complained that no nvidia graphics card was found. After running windows update, it now has a, fully functional, Intel HD graphics card. I first thought it was a software issue, but after rebooting to windows 7, exactly the same thing happened.

Is it possible that the graphics card downgrades itself to an intel HD graphics when the nvidia card breaks down? Or is this some a software/driver problem?

Comment: This isn't an electrical design question, and should be moved to the Super User SE site as it's PC-specific.

Comment: Jeroen - If this doesn't get migrated by a mod, ask this over at SU as madmanguruman says, it should be on topic there.

Comment: Check BIOS/UEFI settings for graphics cards. There is probably an option to choose in which case the Intel card should be used and in which cases nVidia card should be used. It's also possible that the nVidia card died and computer automatically switched to Intel, but I doubt it would be that smart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the newer computers have two graphic cards, one to use for low-intensity tasks, and another for high-quality graphics (games, HD-movies, etc). It might indeed be possible for your NVidia to be damaged and the integrated Intel to take over all tasks.

Try booting from a Live Linux DVD and see whether it recognizes both cards. Good luck!